# Error when trying to upload to go daddy: Class '\App\User' not found

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

I am having a problem hosting my Laravel project. The views work fine, but the error it gives is

> Class '\App\User' not found

even though it works fine on my local machine.

Comment: did you run composer install? it needs to generate the classmaps

Comment: check the spelling of "User" with case. Case its case sensitive.

Comment: help guy i have tried everything  on  the previous section it is working on my system just to upload it is the problem

Comment: the views are even working u can check it out http://www.africaninventorsinnovate.com/

Comment: Run `composer dumpautoload` on the server you've uploaded it to. It needs to rebuild the autoload file.

Comment: Also, what is the path and namespace to `User`?

Comment: composer install  on godaddy???

Comment: Yes. You'll need shell access enabled so you can log in and do that.

Comment: how do i get started with the shell access on windows is it an ssh like putty